# Acceleration of Gravity in python

Tags: python, scripting

I am a beginner trying to figure out a workbook challenge in zybooks.  I need to figure out how to figure out the acceleration of gravity in Python.

```
G = 6.673e-11
M = 5.98e24
accel_gravity = 0.0

dist_center = float(input())

accel_gravity = (G * M) / dist_center**3

print('Acceleration of gravity: {:.2f}'.format(accel_gravity))
```

The output came out wrong.

Testing with input: 6.3782e6 (100m above the Earth's surface at equator)
Output differs. See highlights below.
Your output
Acceleration of gravity: 0.00
Expected output
Acceleration of gravity: 9.81

Any tips?

Comment: This seems like a physics question rather than programming as your equation is incorrect.

Comment: @SMeznaric you're right, but it needs to be solved anyway

Comment: As @Cardstdani  mentioned in the formula for acceleration due to gravity r^3 comes if direction of the acceleration also needs to be mentioned. Otherwise its just r^2
The Formula is g = GM/r^2 (Magnitude)  or g = gM/r^3 r(cap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should power `dist_center` to 2 instead of 3:

```
G = 6.673e-11
M = 5.98e24
accel_gravity = 0.0

dist_center = float(input())

accel_gravity = (G * M) / dist_center**2

print('Acceleration of gravity: {:.2f}'.format(accel_gravity))
```